# Debugging and rebuilding a .net core web app

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

How do I actually run the debugger with a .net core web app using visual studio along side the dotnet watch tool?

I am using the dot net watch tool which greats work and picks up changes, however if I try to attach the debugger, the code doesn't match with what's compiled. So I have to ctrl-c and stop the hosted app, rebuild and rerun donet run and reattach the app to the dotnet process. Surely this can't be the workflow of .net core developers?